# AJAX call fired multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php application to upload excel files to server.I use ajax to send data to server.But some times the ajax call works repeatedly.I called the ajax function in button click as

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnContinue", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ExcelColDesptn.php",
        data: data,                           
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {}
    });
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btnContinue" name="btnContinue" class="btn btn-primary ">Continue </button>
```

I use firebug to fix it, it shows [image]

I don't know why it happens. Here 'ExcelColDesptn.php' is called 3 times and 'SaveExcelToServer.php' is called 4 times. Sometimes it works exactly 1 time. Any help?

Comment: Could you also post your HTML. Are there any other events which raise a click event on that button?

Comment: Can you show the HTML of `btnContinue`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe it's a bind or subscribe, you can be right =)

Comment: <button id="btnContinue" name="btnContinue" class="btn btn-primary ">Continue </button>  . no other event is fired on this button

Comment: @Sherin look at firebug or developer tools in any other browser how many listeners are added to the document and directly to that button or its parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have, is this binding in another function? Which is called multiple times? Because this is a LIVE binding which means, the binding exists even if the content is update.

So I expect the following:

- You use ajax to update content
- #btnContinue is inside an HTML element which is updated by Ajax?
- You call the function to add a new binding to the button
- The button gets an extra click binding
- so the more times you update your ajax, the more times the upload is executed. Because of the way you bind your click.

Solution:

1. Make it a normal binding `$("#btnContinue").on("click", fn)`
2. Put your binding only in document ready, and not in a function which is called multiple times
3. use `$("#btnContinue").off("click")` before your new binding (which is the most ugly solution)

Comment: ExcelColDesptn.php is loded by ajax.but its one time

Answer (score 2):

```
please use your code like this

$('#btnContinue').Click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ExcelColDesptn.php",
        data: data,                           
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: This did not work in opera browser for me. When i select option and hit enter button nothing happened. For firefox and chrome it works.

Comment: When you hit enter did your button click event work in opera browser?

Comment: It was opera browser version issue. After updating opera browser it is working fine.